# How destroy Boostrap 3 modal dialog from DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, twitter-bootstrap-3

I call content for modal dialog from ajax

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "/Clerk/PauseServiceDialog",
    success: function (data) {
        $("body").append(data);
        $("#pauseServiceDialog").modal({ keyboard: false });
    }
});
```

When I close modal I use this code

```
  $(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', ".modal", function (e) {
    this.remove();
});
```

In firebug I see html code is deleted. But if I again call dialog and use some event I get 2 event. How I understand modal dialog do not correct  deleted from DOM.

Answer (score 1):

I found answer how fix duplicate event.

```
 $(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', ".modal", function (e) {
    var name = "#" + $(this).find("button.btn-primary").attr("id");
    $("body").off("click", name);
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide modal  by code

```
   $("#pauseServiceDialog").data('bs.modal').hide()
```

P.S. sorry, i didn't understand notation $(document).on('hidden.bs.modal'  in general - you should delete modal element AND object which handle its events ( it stored at $("#pauseServiceDialog").data('bs.modal') )

Comment: I can't understand your post. I can hide dialog. But I can't remove content from DOM. And my events are repeated.